# I couldn't find Keep Identity in SSIS(SQL Server Integration Services)

Tags: ssis

I know that there is a KEEP IDENTITY option in SSIS.
But I couldn't find Keep Identity in SSIS.
I need that option.

I have Visual Studio 2022 in my computer and SQLServer in Azure.
I have already connected to the database and was able to migrate the data without any problems.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you have is for the OLE DB *Source* Editor. The OLE DB *Destination* Editor is where the Keep Identity Property is located.